# flask does not see rauth even if installed

Tags: python, flask, rauth

I am following [this simple example](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/oauth-authentication-with-flask) to set up a OAuth simple app but something very odd happens: `flask` raise an error related to module `rauth` absence even if it is installed!

Here the commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-oauth-example.git
python3.9 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
(venv) pip install -r requirements.txt    ### out: Successfully installed Flask-0.10.1 Flask-Login-0.3.1 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0 Jinja2-2.7.3 MarkupSafe-0.23 SQLAlchemy-0.9.8 Werkzeug-0.9.6 argparse-1.2.1 itsdangerous-0.24 rauth-0.7.0 requests-2.4.3

(venv) flask run
```

and it returns:

```
Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/enrico/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/enrico/columbia/app/diagnosticator-server-00/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from oauth import OAuthSignIn
  File "/home/enrico/columbia/app/diagnosticator-server-00/oauth.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rauth import OAuth1Service, OAuth2Service
ImportError: No module named rauth
```

but if I check from `venv`:

```
source venv/bin/activate
(venv) python
from rauth import OAuth1Service, OAuth2Service
```

it works with no problem!

And same if I run app.py from outside `flask`:

```
(venv) python app.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

and works with no problem!

Any idea?!

Comment: Your commands in the beginning mention python3.9, but your cli.py is located in the site-packages of python 2.7. I guess your working with 2 different versions mixed (maybe the CLI is not in your venv)?